# jQuery get the rendered height of an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, height

How do you get the rendered height of an element?

Let's say you have a `<div>` element with some content inside. This content inside is going to stretch the height of the `<div>`. How do you get the "rendered" height when you haven't explicitly set the height. Obviously, I tried:

```
var h = document.getElementById('someDiv').style.height;
```

Is there a trick for doing this? I am using jQuery if that helps.

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581307/how-can-i-get-the-height-of-a-dynamicly-varying-div-using-javascript/19581626#19581626

Answer (score 202, accepted):

It should just be

```
$('#someDiv').height();
```

with jQuery. This retrieves the height of the first item in the wrapped set as a number.

Trying to use

```
.style.height
```

only works if you have set the property in the first place. Not very useful!

Comment: even if you're NOT using jQuery or cant or don't want to I strongly suggest anyone implementing this by using just offsetHeight goes ahead and downloads the jQuery source and searches for "height" to find the code they use. lots of crazy stuff going on in there !

Comment: Absolutely agree with that Simon. It's always insightful to investigate how Javascript libraries accomplish a solution to a problem

Comment: @matejkramny - This question and answer was **over 5 years ago**. The OP was already using jQuery on their site so rather than re-implement the same/similar logic him/herself, why not use the one line jQuery function that already does it? I'd agree that jQuery is overkill for a lot of things and I'm not afraid of vanilla JS, but when there is a function in a library that does exactly what you need, it seems silly not to use it, particularly for reasons of "Not Invented Here"

Comment: @RussCam Ok thats a good point.. I would add that it doesn't help you (or the random visitor) learn what actually happens behind the scenes. Too many answers provide one-line 'jquery' solution that yes, works, however it doesn't educate anybody in terms of what happens with the DOM and how it works

Comment: @matejkramny The OPs intention when asking the question was to get the rendered height of the element, not to understand what's happening in the DOM and behind the scenes; if that was their intention, they asked the wrong question. I agree that people should be inclined to understand the libraries and frameworks they use, knowledge is power and all that, but sometimes one just wants an answer to a specific question. Indeed, the above comments already suggest looking through the jQuery code to understand what's going on behind the scenes.

Comment: For the OP, using jQuery is a valid answer. For the rest of the world seeing this from then on, the non-jQuery answer is the best one. Perhaps SO needs to adapt to that reality, maybe highest voted answers should be highlighted in some way more than accepted ones.

Comment: This doesn't return the value in `px` when the height is set in `%` (e.g. 100%). The other answer, `document.getElementById('someDiv').getBoundingClientRect().height` returns the correct value in px.

Answer (score 1303):

Try one of:

```
var h = document.getElementById('someDiv').clientHeight;
var h = document.getElementById('someDiv').offsetHeight;
var h = document.getElementById('someDiv').scrollHeight;
```

`clientHeight` includes the height and vertical padding.

`offsetHeight` includes the height, vertical padding, and vertical borders.

`scrollHeight` includes the height of the contained document (would be greater than just height in case of scrolling), vertical padding, and vertical borders.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about this property. It is IE8+ compatible also.

Comment: I'm perplexed with the meaning of clientHeight. I have a div element which has a bunch of p elements in it and the content goes far beyond the viewable area of the browser downward. And I expected clientHeight to give the rendered height, and scrollHeight to give the full length. But they are almost equal ( only differing by margin, padding etc.) .

Comment: @bahti unless it itself has a limited height and an overflow:hidden or some form of overflow:scroll, the element will expand (whether in your view or not) to show all the content and scrollHeight and clientHeight will be equal.

Comment: Great answer, but logically, the borders that affect the height of an element are the top and bottom borders, which are horizontal. This answer refers to them as "vertical borders." Just thought I'd drop my 2 cents

Comment: From what I know, `.clientWidth/.clientHeight` **do NOT include scroll width** if scroll is shown. If you want scroll width to be included, can use `element.getBoundingClientRect().width ` instead

Comment: `scrollHeight` does **not** include borders, please see MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight

Answer (score 155):

***NON JQUERY*** *since there were a bunch of links using `elem.style.height` in the top of these answers...*

INNER HEIGHT:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.clientHeight

```
document.getElementById(id_attribute_value).clientHeight;
```

OUTER HEIGHT:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetHeight

```
document.getElementById(id_attribute_value).offsetHeight;
```

Or one of my favorite references: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Answer (score 59):

I use this to get the height of an element *(returns float)*:

```
document.getElementById('someDiv').getBoundingClientRect().height
```

It also works when you use the *virtual DOM*. I use it in Vue like this:

```
this.$refs['some-ref'].getBoundingClientRect().height
```

For a Vue component:

```
this.$refs['some-ref'].$el.getBoundingClientRect().height
```

Comment: getBoundingClientRect().height returns a floating-point number (while the others return integer), nice :)

Answer (score 51):

You can use `.outerHeight()` for this purpose.

It will give you full rendered height of the element. Also, you don't need to set any `css-height` of the element. For precaution you can keep its height **auto** so it can be rendered as per content's height.

```
//if you need height of div excluding margin/padding/border
$('#someDiv').height();

//if you need height of div with padding but without border + margin
$('#someDiv').innerHeight();

// if you need height of div including padding and border
$('#someDiv').outerHeight();

//and at last for including border + margin + padding, can use
$('#someDiv').outerHeight(true);
```

For a clear view of these function you can go for jQuery's site or a [**detailed post here**](https://17path.wordpress.com/2013/01/30/how-to-get-height-of-an-element-in-jquery/).

it will clear the *difference* between `.height()` / `innerHeight()` / `outerHeight()`

Answer (score 32):

```
style = window.getComputedStyle(your_element);
```

then simply: `style.height`

Answer (score 15):

Definitely use

```
$('#someDiv').height()   // to read it
```

or

```
$('#someDiv').height(newHeight)  // to set it
```

I'm posting this as an additional answer because theres a couple important things I just learnt.

I almost fell into the trap just now of using offsetHeight. This is what happened :

- I used the good old trick of using a debugger to 'watch' what properties my element has
- I saw which one has a value around the value I was expecting
- It was offsetHeight - so I used that.
- Then i realized it didnt work with a hidden DIV
- I tried hiding after calculating maxHeight but that looked clumsy - got in a mess.
- I did a search - discovered jQuery.height() - and used it
- found out height() works even on hidden elements
- just for fun I checked the jQuery implementation of height/width

Here's just a portion of it :

```
Math.max(
Math.max(document.body["scroll" + name], document.documentElement["scroll" + name]),
Math.max(document.body["offset" + name], document.documentElement["offset" + name])
)
```

Yup it looks at BOTH scroll and offset. If that fails it looks even further, taking into account browser and css compatibility issues. In other words STUFF I DONT CARE ABOUT - or want to.

But I dont have to. Thanks jQuery!

Moral of the story : if jQuery has a method for something its probably for a good reason, likely related to compatibilty.

If you haven't read through the [jQuery list of methods](https://api.jquery.com) recently I suggest you take a look.

Comment: Saw your other comment at the question level. I'm sold on jQuery. Have been for a little while. But this sealed the deal. I'm in love with the fact this simple thing is going to solve 100s of layout issues for me (mostly on Intranet sites where I know JavaScript is running).

Answer (score 14):

I think the best way to do this in 2020 is to use vanilla js and `getBoundingClientRect().height;`

Here's an example

```js
let div = document.querySelector('div');
let divHeight = div.getBoundingClientRect().height;

console.log(`Div Height: ${divHeight}`);
```

```html
<div>
  How high am I? 
</div>
```

On top of getting `height` this way, we also have access to a bunch of other stuff about the `div`.

```js
let div = document.querySelector('div');
let divInfo = div.getBoundingClientRect();

console.log(divInfo);
```

```html
<div>What else am I? </div>
```

Comment: What does client in the method name mean?

Answer (score 13):

I made a simple code that doesn't even need JQuery and probably gonna help some people.
It gets the total height of 'ID1' after loaded and use it on 'ID2'

```
function anyName(){
    var varname=document.getElementById('ID1').offsetHeight;
    document.getElementById('ID2').style.height=varname+'px';
}
```

Then just set the body to load it

```
<body onload='anyName()'>
```

Answer (score 13):

```
document.querySelector('.project_list_div').offsetHeight;
```

Comment: This property will round the value to an **integer**. If you need a **float** value, use `elem.getBoundingClientRect().height`

Answer (score 11):

Hm we can get the Element geometry...

```
var geometry;
geometry={};
var element=document.getElementById(#ibims);
var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
this.geometry.top=rect.top;
this.geometry.right=rect.right;
this.geometry.bottom=rect.bottom;
this.geometry.left=rect.left;
this.geometry.height=this.geometry.bottom-this.geometry.top;
this.geometry.width=this.geometry.right-this.geometry.left;
console.log(this.geometry);
```

How about this plain JS ?

Comment: `var geometry;
geometry={};` can simply be `var geometry={};`

Answer (score 8):

So is this the answer?

"If you need to calculate something but not show it, set the element to `visibility:hidden` and `position:absolute`, add it to the DOM tree, get the offsetHeight, and remove it. (That's what the prototype library does behind the lines last time I checked)."

I have the same problem on a number of elements.  There is no jQuery or Prototype to be used on the site but I'm all in favor of borrowing the technique if it works.  As an example of some things that failed to work, followed by what did, I have the following code:

```
// Layout Height Get
function fnElementHeightMaxGet(DoScroll, DoBase, elementPassed, elementHeightDefault)
{
    var DoOffset = true;
    if (!elementPassed) { return 0; }
    if (!elementPassed.style) { return 0; }
    var thisHeight = 0;
    var heightBase = parseInt(elementPassed.style.height);
    var heightOffset = parseInt(elementPassed.offsetHeight);
    var heightScroll = parseInt(elementPassed.scrollHeight);
    var heightClient = parseInt(elementPassed.clientHeight);
    var heightNode = 0;
    var heightRects = 0;
    //
    if (DoBase) {
        if (heightBase > thisHeight) { thisHeight = heightBase; }
    }
    if (DoOffset) {
        if (heightOffset > thisHeight) { thisHeight = heightOffset; }
    }
    if (DoScroll) {
        if (heightScroll > thisHeight) { thisHeight = heightScroll; }
    }
    //
    if (thisHeight == 0) { thisHeight = heightClient; }
    //
    if (thisHeight == 0) { 
        // Dom Add:
        // all else failed so use the protype approach...
        var elBodyTempContainer = document.getElementById('BodyTempContainer');
        elBodyTempContainer.appendChild(elementPassed);
        heightNode = elBodyTempContainer.childNodes[0].offsetHeight;
        elBodyTempContainer.removeChild(elementPassed);
        if (heightNode > thisHeight) { thisHeight = heightNode; }
        //
        // Bounding Rect:
        // Or this approach...
        var clientRects = elementPassed.getClientRects();
        heightRects = clientRects.height;
        if (heightRects > thisHeight) { thisHeight = heightRects; }
    }
    //
    // Default height not appropriate here
    // if (thisHeight == 0) { thisHeight = elementHeightDefault; }
    if (thisHeight > 3000) {
        // ERROR
        thisHeight = 3000;
    }
    return thisHeight;
}
```

which basically tries anything and everything only to get a zero result. ClientHeight with no affect.  With the problem elements I typically get NaN in the Base and zero in the Offset and Scroll heights.  I then tried the Add DOM solution and clientRects to see if it works here.

29 Jun 2011,
I did indeed update the code to try both adding to DOM and clientHeight with better results than I expected.

1) clientHeight was also 0.

2) Dom actually gave me a height which was great.

3) ClientRects returns a result almost identical to the DOM technique.

Because the elements added are fluid in nature, when they are added to an otherwise empty DOM Temp element they are rendered according to the width of that container.  This get weird, because that is 30px shorter than it eventually ends up.

I added a few snapshots to illustrate how the height is calculated differently.
[image: Menu block rendered normally]
[image: Menu block added to DOM Temp element]

The height differences are obvious.   I could certainly add absolute positioning and hidden but I am sure that will have no effect.  I continued to be convinced this would not work!

(I digress further) The height comes out (renders) lower than the true rendered height.  This could be addressed by setting the width of the DOM Temp element to match the existing parent and could be done fairly accurately in theory.  I also do not know what would result from removing them and adding them back into their existing location.  As they arrived through an innerHTML technique I will be looking using this different approach.

*** HOWEVER *** None of that was necessary. In fact it worked as advertised and returned the correct height!!!

When I was able to get the menus visible again amazingly DOM had returned the correct height per the fluid layout at the top of the page (279px).  The above code also uses getClientRects which return 280px.

This is illustrated in the following snapshot (taken from Chrome once working.)
[image]

Now I have noooooo idea why that prototype trick works, but it seems to.  Alternatively, getClientRects also works.

I suspect the cause of all this trouble with these particular elements was the use of innerHTML instead of appendChild, but that is pure speculation at this point.

Answer (score 6):

`offsetHeight`, usually.

If you need to calculate something but not show it, set the element to `visibility:hidden` and `position:absolute`, add it to the DOM tree, get the `offsetHeight`, and remove it. (That's what the prototype library does behind the scenes last time I checked).

Comment: interesting. i've never checked prototype. any idea why jQuery doesn't do that behind the scenes?

Comment: I saw that when having difficulties and tested out that technique and it worked quite well in plain JavaScript

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes offsetHeight will return zero because the element you've created has not been rendered in the Dom yet. I wrote this function for such circumstances:

```
function getHeight(element)
{
    var e = element.cloneNode(true);
    e.style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.body.appendChild(e);
    var height = e.offsetHeight + 0;
    document.body.removeChild(e);
    e.style.visibility = "visible";
    return height;
}
```

Comment: you need to clone the element otherwise it'll be removed from the dom completely it seems from your code that's what'll happen.

Comment: This code is not intended to keep the element in the DOM. It is intended to put it into the DOM just briefly (long enough to render it and get its height), then it takes it out. You can later put the element into the dom elsewhere later (knowing what its height will be before you do). Notice the function name "getHeight"; that's all that the code intends to do.

Comment: @punkbit : I see what you mean. Your element is already in the dom. The code I wrote is for an element that is not yet in the DOM. Cloning would be better, as you say, because it wouldn't matter if the element is in the dom or not.

Comment: @punkbit : I modified the code use cloning, but have not tested it.

Comment: yeah, that was my point. Seemed to me that he says "element" for an existing element in the DOM. But all good! Don't get it wrong.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using jQuery already, your best bet is `.outerHeight()` or `.height()`, as has been stated.

Without jQuery, you can check the box-sizing in use and add up various paddings + borders + clientHeight, *or* you can use [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle):

var h = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('someDiv')).height;

`h` will now be a string like a "53.825px".

And I can't find the reference, but I think I heard `getComputedStyle()` can be expensive, so it's probably not something you want to call on each `window.onscroll` event (but then, neither is jQuery's `height()`).

Comment: Once you have the height from `getComputedStyle`, use `parseInt(h, 10)` to get a integer for calculations.

Answer (score 2):

With **MooTools**:

`$('someDiv').getSize().y`

Answer (score 1):

If i understood your question correctly, then maybe something like this would help:

```
function testDistance(node1, node2) {
    /* get top position of node 1 */
    let n1Pos = node1.offsetTop;
    /* get height of node 1 */
    let n1Height = node1.clientHeight;
    /* get top position of node 2 */
    let n2Pos = node2.offsetTop;
    /* get height of node 2 */
    let n2Height = node2.clientHeight;

    /* add height of both nodes */
    let heightTogether = n1Height + n2Height;
    /* calculate distance from top of node 1 to bottom of node 2 */
    let actualDistance = (n2Pos + n2Height) - n1Pos;

    /* if the distance between top of node 1 and bottom of node 2
       is bigger than their heights combined, than there is something between them */
    if (actualDistance > heightTogether) {
        /* do something here if they are not together */
        console.log('they are not together');
    } else {
        /* do something here if they are together */
        console.log('together');
    } 
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Have you set the height in the css specifically? If you haven't you need to use `offsetHeight;` rather than `height`

```
var h = document.getElementById('someDiv').style.offsetHeight;
```

Comment: offsetHeight is a property of the element itself, not of its style.