# How to get height of <div> in px dimension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have used jQuery library to find out height of a `div`.

Below is my `div` element with attributes :

```
<DIV id="myDiv" style="height:auto; width:78;overflow:hidden"> Simple Test</DIV>
```

Below is my jQuery code to get height of `<div>`

```
var result = $("#myDiv").css('height');
alert(result);
```

After executing above statement I am getting result as "auto". Actually this is I am not expecting, instead of that I **want the result in px dimension.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get the rendered height of an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526347/how-do-you-get-the-rendered-height-of-an-element)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Use [`.height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) like this:

```
var result = $("#myDiv").height();
```

There's also [`.innerHeight()`](http://api.jquery.com/innerHeight/) and [`.outerHeight()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/) depending on *exactly* what you want.

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/kTkHS/1/), play with the padding/margins/content to see how it changes around.

Comment: Ah, what the hell. +1 for beating me by a minute instead of the usual 2-20 seconds.

Comment: I always get 1 when I use this method.

Comment: @AndroidAddict is your content all floated inside the div by chance? if so give it an `overflow: auto` so the height expands to the floats correctly. This is just how floats behave, give it a border to see what I mean.

Answer (score 151):

Although they vary slightly as to how they retrieve a height value, i.e some would calculate the whole element including padding, margin, scrollbar, etc and others would just calculate the element in its raw form.
You can try these ones:

javascript:

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
myDiv.clientHeight;
myDiv.scrollHeight;
myDiv.offsetHeight;
```

or in jquery:

```
$("#myDiv").height();
$("#myDiv").innerHeight();
$("#myDiv").outerHeight();
```

Comment: Very useful for translate to javascript when you want to avoid jQuery

Comment: Most of answers tem to Forget 'scrollHeight'! And.... most of the times, when system is sort of Bootstraped multi-layered... it's the real one! Thanks!

You couls use Math.round(Math.max(bodyDiv.clientHeight, bodyDiv.scrollHeight, bodyDiv.offsetHeight) || 0)

Answer (score 33):

Use [`height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/):

```
var result = $("#myDiv").height();
alert(result);
```

This will give you the unit-less computed height in pixels. "px" will be stripped from the result. I.e. if the height is 400px, the result will be 400, but the result will be in pixels.

If you want to do it **without** jQuery, you can use plain JavaScript:

```
var result = document.getElementById("myDiv").offsetHeight;
```

Comment: Note that `element.offsetHeight` [does not take into account](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45419412/3423324) any transforms (e.g. `transform: scale(0.5)`). If you need those, `element.getBoundingClientRect().height` is better suited.

Answer (score 2):

There is a built-in method to get the bounding rectangle: [`Element.getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect).

> The result is the smallest rectangle which contains the entire
>   element, with the read-only left, top, right, bottom, x, y, width, and
>   ***height*** properties.

See the example below:

```js
let innerBox = document.getElementById("myDiv").getBoundingClientRect().height;
document.getElementById("data_box").innerHTML = "height: " + innerBox;
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.relative {
  width: 220px;
  height: 180px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: purple;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 20px;
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#myDiv {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#data_box {
  font: 30px arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
Get height of <mark>myDiv</mark> in px dimension:
<div id="data_box"></div>
<div class="relative">
  <div class="absolute">
    <div id="myDiv">myDiv</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For those looking for a plain JS solution:

```
let el = document.querySelector("#myElementId");

// including the element's border
let width = el.offsetWidth;
let height = el.offsetHeight;

// not including the element's border:
let width = el.clientWidth;
let height = el.clientHeight;
```

Check out [this article](https://plainjs.com/javascript/styles/getting-width-and-height-of-an-element-23/) for more details.