# How can I resize elements dynamically while using react?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a grid of components with 3 per row.

They are divs which represent a product and have inner components such as price and description. These products sometimes have longer titles which push the other components downward.

This is fine, but when it happens I want the titles for the other components in the same row to have a height the same, so that the next components  (price, rating) are vertically aligned. So the price for each product in a row will be the same.

Then, I want to make the height of the row the max height of the three elements in the row.

Is there a good way I can manipulate the height of elements dynamically which will work with react?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would inject a function in all child components which is called after the child component is rendered.

Example:

```
var Product = React.createClass({

  componentDidMount: function() {
    var height = 200; // calculate height of rendered component here!
    // set height only one time
    if (this.props.findHeight) {
        this.props.setHeight(height);
    }
  },

  render: function() {
    return <div style={{height:this.props.height,backgroundColor:'green'}}>
            Product
        </div>;
  }
});

var Main = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      maxHeight:0,
      findHeight: true
    }
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.setState({
        maxHeight: this.state.maxHeight,
        findHeight: false
    });
  },

  setMaxHeight: function(maxHeight) {
    if (maxHeight > this.state.maxHeight) {
      this.setState({maxHeight: maxHeight})
    }
  },

  render: function() {
    return (<div>
             <Product setHeight={this.setMaxHeight} height={this.state.maxHeight} findHeight={this.state.findHeight} />
           </div>);
  }
});
```

The logic how to calculate the actual height of a component is a different question. You can solve it e.g. with jQuery ([How to get height of <div> in px dimension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839227/how-to-get-height-of-div-in-px-dimension)). Unfortunately I can not answer the question for vanilla js, but I am sure that you find the answer very fast when you ask google :-)

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

By extending the answer provided by [CapCa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36677473/7430118), you can get the actual height of the component by [Element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect).

```
let domRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
```

You can also target the top element of your targeted react component by using [React Ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html). Your code could be like this,

```
let domRect = this.TargetedElementRef.getBoundingClientRect(),
    elementHeight = domRect.height,
    elementWidth = domRect.width;   // you can get the width also
```