# JavaScript getBoundingClientRect() vs offsetHeight while calculate element height

Tags: javascript

What is the best way to get element height:

```
var myElement = document.querySelector('.some-class');

var height = myElement.getBoundingClientRect().height;
```

or

```
var myElement = document.querySelector('.some-class');

var height = myElement.offsetHeight;
```

Answer (score 58):

Most of the time these are the same as width and height of `getBoundingClientRect()`, when there aren't any transforms applied to the element. In case of transforms, the `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight` returns the element's layout width and height, while `getBoundingClientRect()` returns the rendering width and height. As an example, if the element has width: 100px; and transform: scale(0.5); the `getBoundingClientRect()` will return 50 as the width, while offsetWidth will return 100.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Determining_the_dimensions_of_elements

Comment: What about `el.clientHeight` ?

Comment: @mesqueeb Take a look at how `clientHeight` works. It depends on what you need.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Determining_the_dimensions_of_elements

Comment: Thanks! In case someone comes looking here. This answer was also reaaaally helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106538/difference-between-offsetheight-and-clientheight