# How to return the height of a div in pixels?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a function that would return the pixel height of a div? I want to add images to the side of said div based on the size of the div (which would be dependent on the user's content, and would change the size of the div)

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: If so (try googling this stuff first) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592575/get-height-of-div-with-no-height-set-in-css

Comment: Are you using any javascript lib, such as jQuery?

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6101230/1257652)? there are plenty of examples of this all over the place

Comment: Oops sorry guys, I literally just looked up 'height of div in pixels' in google and stack, and didn't get any results that you guys got. Sorry again, and thanks for the help.

Comment: you didn't? O_O http://www.google.com/search?q=height+of+div+in+pixels

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementById('divId').offsetHeight` should give you the height.

Answer (score 1):

If using jQuery:

```
<div id="something">...</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#something").height();
```

Comment: This question has obviously been asked and answered before; no need to re-post.

Comment: also no jQuery use was mentioned