# Get height of a component in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I am using Primefaces in my Webapplication and wonder if there is a way to get the height of a specific component in my `xhtml`.

In my example i have a (from a database) generated `<p:tieredMenu>` and need to know the height of this component to layout other components.
I already looked in the `FacesContext` but haven't found anything relevant to my problem.

Maybe someone can give me a hint how to find those settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height is dependent on how the browser has rendered this.

You can check it in JavaScript

```
$('#myElement').height()
```

See also: [CSS / JavaScript - How do you get the rendered height of an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526347/css-javascript-how-do-you-get-the-rendered-height-of-an-element)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i would prefer to do it without JS. I would prefer a way in plain JSF or eben better with the help of Java and the FacesContext or similar.

Comment: But the size of the component is client-side property, you won't have it on server side.