# How can i get the height of a dynamicly varying div using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there anyway to get the height of a dynamic div using javascript?I have a dynamic div which is populated by contents dynamically.I want to know div's height each time.
Can anybody help me to figure it out?

Comment: Do you know after which event the height of the div increasing? If you know, use the script <code>document.getElementById('your divid').height()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2XzR9/).

You can set/get the **Height** of DIV from [height Property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_height.asp)

Example Code is,

```
document.getElementById("demo").style.height;

document.getElementById("demo").style.height="100px";
```

If you set height in CSS means, use [`JQuery`](http://api.jquery.com/height/).

Answer (score 2):

This might help you

`document.getElementById("div1").clientHeight`

Answer (score -1):

You can use .height(), .innerHeight() or outerHeight() based on what you need.

.height() - returns the height of element excludes padding, border and margin.

.innerHeight() - returns the height of element includes padding but excludes border and margin.

.outerHeight() - returns the height of the div including border but excludes margin.

.outerHeight(true) - returns the height of the div including margin.