# CSS print style for a fixed footer on the last page

Tags: html, css, pdf

I have an HTML article that is supposed to be optimized for printing, so I added a print stylesheet. When I try to fix the  to the bottom of the last page it is always positioned after the last bit of content instead of the bottom of the last page.

[image: PDF Preview]

Is there any way to have the footer fixed to the bottom of the last page only?

Comment: could the it be accounting for the print margins?

Comment: I tried @page { margin: 0 0 0 0 } makes no difference unfortunately. ( regarding the position of the footer )

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21032137/sticking-custom-footer-on-each-page-to-bottom-while-printing

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
#footer {
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: -40px;
}
```

Comment: This works if I set the HTML file up from scratch however it does not work if I try to apply it on an existing HTML structure with a lot of nested divs. Anyways I believe the problem is on my side and your answer provides the proper solution. Thank you.

Comment: @derp maybe you can give 1 div or your footer a class and use `.footer`

Comment: It is not the soluion to the problem after all. There is no way to make a footer stick to the bottom of the last page of a multi page document unless maybe you're restricted to FF only or refactor the entire HTML e.g. working with a table structure or nested divs, setting the height of the outer div to 100% each. It does not work for a continous "document" that spreads over multiple pages.