# How to footer at the end of the every page

Tags: html, css

I want to add footer in the end of the page after every page-break in the html.

here is the html code(here when the content of the container is overflow i want to add footer at that page as well as on the second page it creates after the page-break):

```
<html>
<head>
 ...
 <style>
  .container {
    width: 695px;
    height: 1022px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 40px;
    color: #495057;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
  }
  .footer{
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: red;
   text-align: center;
   page-break-after: always;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
 ...
 </div>
 <div class="footer">
 ...
 </div>
<body>
</html>
```

Output ( as we can see in the output it only gives the footer in the first page but i want it in the second page as well):

[image]

Comment: Pls add HTML of both pages

Comment: @ArchitGargi it is the html of the both pages!! I am generating pdf of this html. :)

Comment: This question already has answers here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page

Comment: @HosseinShourabi no! I think when the new page is created because of the overflowing content I want the footer on that page as well!! ( sorry I am not good at explaining the problem :)

Comment: Do you want have the footer in "print" screen in all pages?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21032137/sticking-custom-footer-on-each-page-to-bottom-while-printing

Comment: @HosseinShourabi yes sir! on every pages!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [csi.js](https://github.com/LexmarkWeb/csi.js?files=1) .

u will need to add the `csi.min.js` file in your `<head>`.

Make a `footer.html`

and add this to every page where u want that file to be included, in this case at last where u want your footer to be.

```
<body>

 //Your page

 <div data-include="footer.html"></div>

</body>
```

***Edit:***

I found this in their readme. try adding

```
   "footer": {
    "height": "28mm",
    "contents": {
      first: 'Cover page',
      2: 'Second page', // Any page number is working. 1-based index
      default: '<span style="color: #444;">{{page}}</span>/<span>{{pages}}</span>', // fallback value
      last: 'Last Page'
    }
  },
```

to config

Comment: It's not a different page! it is only one page! I am generating the pdf of that page and it generates 2 page pdf! I want footer on both the pages! I know the height of the pdf pages! how to add footer on each page!

Comment: may i know how are u generating pdf of ur page?

Comment: I am generating pdf using "html-pdf" package in NodeJS.

Comment: I have added something in the answer. check if it helps out