# Placing the footer at the bottom of page

Tags: css, html, css-position

I am having trouble placing the footer at the bottom of the page. For some strange reason it keeps appearing near the top. Here is a link to [the page](http://focusfotos.com.mt/v1/index.php/aboutus/bio). I want the footer to appear beneath the text content. Any help will be much appreciated as I'm stuck:/

Thanks

Comment: solved using this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/11741786/3386878

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Your `<footer>` is inside `<div id="main_container"> ... </div>`. You have to move it outside of it. I recommend you not using position absolute for such an easy website. You should learn how to use CSS first.

Here is a [printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csygN.png) for you.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply...yes I might need to refresh my CSS...your solution places the footer at the bottom of the browser window not the page.

Answer (score 0):

Put the footer outside the `<div id='main_container'>`
And it will work.