# change height of div by clicking it

Tags: javascript, css

I want to change the height of the div by clicking it.

**Why it doesn't work at the first clicking but the second?**

I don't know why, but the height of the div is `""` (in the second clicking is `20px` because of the `else condition`)

If I define the height of the div in the html element (style="height: 20px"), it works.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function divOpen() {
        var divHeight= document.getElementById("divBottom").style.height;
        if (divHeight=="20px") {
        document.getElementById("divBottom").style.height="200px"; 
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("divBottom").style.height="20px"; 
        }
    }


</script>

    <style>
        div{
            border:solid 1px gray; 
            width:200px;
            height:20px;   
        }
        .divBottom {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
        right: 20px;
        cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="divBottom" id="divBottom" onclick="divOpen()"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**so I know how to fix it, but I don't know why the height is empty in the first clicking.**

Please let me know..

any help appreciated!

Comment: The height of the `div` is empty because you haven't specified it anywhere. The browser will calculate it based on the content.

Comment: but I defined it in the style..

Comment: Nobody ever makes [a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gUwmr/)! (Pasted your code in)

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS / JavaScript - How do you get the rendered height of an element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526347/css-javascript-how-do-you-get-the-rendered-height-of-an-element)

Comment: it's not possible cause I know how to fix it.. please read my question again..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the initial click the `height` style property of your div is `''` because you haven't set it.

There is a difference between setting height through the style property and by using a class. Try to refactor your code and make it use `offsetHeight` instead of `style.height`.

**JavaScript**

```
function divOpen() {
  var divHeight= document.getElementById("divBottom").offsetHeight;
  console.log(divHeight);
  //22 because of the border
  if (divHeight == 22) {
    document.getElementById("divBottom").style.height="200px"; 
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("divBottom").style.height="20px"; 
  }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/mabanoqi/1/edit)

Comment: No need to reference the element by ID... just pass `this` into the function. [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/TB8Bd/1)