# Scroll doesn't work inside multiple divs

Tags: html, css, scroll

Please help me with this

http://jsfiddle.net/5xXwQ/

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="banner"></div>

    <div id="childsparent">
    <div id="child">
        sdsdsdsd?<br>sdsdsdsd?<br>sdsdsdsd?<br>sdsdsdsd?<br>sdsdsdsd?<br>sdsdsdsd?<br>sdsdsdsd?<br>
        sdsdsdsd?<br>sdsdsdsd?<br>sdsdsdsd?<br>sdsdsdsd?<br>sdsdsdsd?<br>sdsdsdsd?<br>sdsdsdsd?<br>
        sdsdsdsd?<br>sdsdsdsd?<br>sdsdsdsd?<br>sdsdsdsd?<br>sdsdsdsd?<br>sdsdsdsd?<br>sdsdsdsd?<br>
        sdsdsdsd?<br>sdsdsdsd?<br>sdsdsdsd?<br>sdsdsdsd?<br>sdsdsdsd?<br>sdsdsdsd?<br>sdsdsdsd?<br>
        sdsdsdsd?<br>sdsdsdsd?<br>sdsdsdsd?<br>sdsdsdsd?<br>sdsdsdsd?<br>sdsdsdsd?<br>sdsdsdsd?<br>
        sdsdsdsd?<br>sdsdsdsd?<br>sdsdsdsd?<br>sdsdsdsd?<br>sdsdsdsd?<br>sdsdsdsd?<br>sdsdsdsd?<br>
        sdsdsdsd?<br>sdsdsdsd?<br>sdsdsdsd?<br>sdsdsdsd?<br>sdsdsdsd?<br>sdsdsdsd?<br>sdsdsdsd?<br>
        sdsdsdsd?<br>sdsdsdsd?<br>sdsdsdsd?<br>sdsdsdsd?<br>sdsdsdsd?<br>sdsdsdsd?<br>sdsdsdsd?<br>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
#parent {
    background: #CCC;
    width:200px;
    height:500px;
}

#banner {
    width:200px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #ff0000;
}

#childsparent {
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

I need to make it scrollable but parent div must be of its height for example 500px.

I know it works when there is only parent and child, but when there is multiple div it is overflowing div and scroll doesnt work. How to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would put `overflow:hidden;` on `#parent`, but you will still have a really tall `#childsparent`. You have to restrict the `#childsparent`. If you know for certain the parent will be 500px tall and `#banner` will be 200px, then set:

```
#childsparent {
    [...]
    height:300px; /*or*/
    max-height:300px;
}
```

If `#childsparent` were the only child of `#parent` then just `#childsparent { ... height:100%; }`. Otherwise, if you won't know the size of `#banner` then pull out some Javascript to do the math.

Comment: That last sentence is exactly what I am looking for... I need to set height to fullfill parent, because I wont have only one scrollable element on page and dont want to make for every one new css height value. What javascript should I use? Thank :)

Comment: @user3780666 Do some Google searches for jQuery.height(), or take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526347/css-javascript-how-do-you-get-the-rendered-height-of-an-element

Answer (score 0):

Here is updated jsfiddle with working example http://jsfiddle.net/5xXwQ/1/

```
#parent {
        background: #CCC;
        width:200px;
        height:500px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

#childsparent {
    height: 500px;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I know that solution work when I set height of px .... also on jsfiddle works when I set there 100% but in my template % doesnt seem to work ...  I have to search what it is... .. thanks anyway

Comment: It works in jsfiddle because you have parent element which has size in pixels and thad browser can deside what is 100%. Also you can add parent element.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `height:450px;` to #childsparent will give you the behavior you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/5xXwQ/7/

```
#parent {
        background: #CCC;
        width:200px;
        height:550px;
    }

    #banner {
        width:200px;
        height: 50px;
        background: #ff0000;
    }

    #childsparent {
        overflow:scroll;
            height:500px;
    }
```