# How to calculate content height by using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have used this code for defining "mainContent div height"
but it alerts `undefined`!

```
window.onload = function () {
    alert(mainContent.height);
}


function viewPort() {
    var pageWrapper = document.getElementById('pageWrapper').offsetHeight;
    pageFooter = document.getElementById('pageFooter').offsetHeight;
    pageHeader = document.getElementById('pageHeader').offsetHeight;
    differenceInHeight = pageWrapper - (pageHeader + pageFooter);
    mainContent = document.getElementById('mainContent').style.height = differenceInHeight + 'px';
};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS / JavaScript - How do you get the rendered height of an element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526347/css-javascript-how-do-you-get-the-rendered-height-of-an-element)

Comment: When you call function `viewPort`?

Comment: Can you include your relevant markup and css please?

Comment: ohhh, sorry got it,  undefine comes bcoz of alert ... ! :P

Comment: hey code is right but due to alert this popups up Undefine...

Comment: Thanks  @henrik, panther, samurai ... for your time