# Get actual size of DIV including overflow (elements exceeding parent bound)

Tags: javascript, html

Consider this example:

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("elem");

alert(elem.offsetHeight + " " + elem.getBoundingClientRect().height);
```

```html
<div id="elem" style="position:relative; width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid black; box-sizing: border-box">
    <div style="position: absolute; bottom: -15px;">Test</div>
</div>
```

As you see my div actual height is 100px (as in its style) plus the exceeding part of its child (overflow). However both `offsetHeight` and `getBoundingClientRect().height` will return 100px, thus not taking into account the overflow part. I would expect something around 115px.

So, how can I get the actual size of an arbitrary DIV taking into account all its children? Possibly please without jQuery.

**EDIT:** Regarding possible duplicate [CSS / JavaScript - How do you get the rendered height of an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526347/css-javascript-how-do-you-get-the-rendered-height-of-an-element), it's not what I was looking for.

Comment: It *is* the actual size, because `position:absolute` takes the element out of the flow and it doesn't affect its parent size.

Comment: `elem.scrollHeight` doesn't count borders by the way

Comment: Well it got set to box-sizing: border-box, change it to padding-box if you want the borders.

Comment: @Lain: thanks! Please turn it as an answer so I can vote it

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS / JavaScript - How do you get the rendered height of an element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526347/css-javascript-how-do-you-get-the-rendered-height-of-an-element)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

elem.scrollHeight

https://jsfiddle.net/LLfeh8nk/

```
alert(elem.scrollHeight + " " + elem.getBoundingClientRect().height);
```