# How to increase Googles polyfill dialog height dynamically

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

I use Googles polyfill dialog and want to increase it's height dynamically depending if a user clicks a dialog button to add more elements (rows) in it.
This is part the javascript which is called when the user cklicks that button :

```
var mc_dialog = document.getElementById('mc_dialog');
var h = mc_dialog.style.height;
console.log("mc_dialog height = ",h);
```

but `height` is simple empty, no value - nothing

While `mc_dialog.style.height = "500px"` works perfect.

Why do I not get the value of `mc_dialog.style.height` ?

EDIT :

Ok after the answer of Evil Penguin I set the height `initially` in the javascript function, which opens the dialog, like this :

```
mc_dialog.style.height = "500px"
```

and later when the user clicks to add content to the dialog I can retrieve the height now, so it look like this now :

```
var mc_dialog = document.getElementById('mc_dialog');
var h = parseInt(mc_dialog.style.height);
mc_dialog.style.height= h+50+"px";
```

and it works perfect.

But now I have the question why do I have to set the style.height initially ? Isn't it a permanent attribute of that element ? And if not,  why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526347/css-javascript-how-do-you-get-the-rendered-height-of-an-element) is similar question.

**.style.height only works if you have set the property in the first place.**

EDIT:

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) is reference of `HTMLElement.style` property. It says:

**The style property is not useful for learning about the element's style in general, since it represents only the CSS declarations set in the element's inline style attribute.**

So as i understand it, if there is no `style="smth"` in the element's inline declaration, `HTMLElement.style.smth` doesn't work.

Comment: first place means initially ? If so - yes . #mc_dialog css has a height of 500px initially.

Comment: see my EDIT above