# WhatsApp Web like Content Editable Div

Tags: html, css, vuejs2, responsive, vuetify.js

I am looking for a way to have a WhatsApp Web like content editable div which expands upwards when pressing SHIFT+ENTER and also minimizes the div above it accordingly (See purple area in the attached screenshots).

What would be the best way to implement this?

Thanks a lot.

Edit: I use vuejs along with vuetify.

[image: Before Pressing SHIFT+ENTER]

[image: After Pressing SHIFT+ENTER]

Comment: please show your code and what you tried so far

Answer (score 1):

**I am using variables in css to `clac` the `height` of `.converstion` `div` :https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_variables.asp**
I am using `Jquery` but you can do it using `Vue JS`
**See JSFiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/8feswyau/**

```js
$('textarea').on({input: function(){
    var totalHeight = $(this).prop('scrollHeight') - parseInt($(this).css('padding-top')) - parseInt($(this).css('padding-bottom'));
    $(this).css({'height':totalHeight});
    $('.conversation').get(0).style.setProperty("--number",totalHeight+'px')
}
});
```

```css
 textarea{
 width:243px;
 
 }
.warp{
height:300px;
width:250px;
}
.conversation{
 height: calc(100% - var(--number));
    position: relative;
    background: #efe7dd url(https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/398893/15136779/4e765036-1639-11e6-9201-67e728e86f39.jpg) repeat;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="warp">
<div class="conversation" style="--number: 12px"></div>
<textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: tell me if you need help

Comment: Thanls for replying. Will check that and reply asap.

Comment: see here how to get height of element in vuejs:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44948714/get-element-height-with-vuejs

Comment: Thank you a lot. I managed to solve this with css and js.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YvEeWr

Comment: nice one... have luck(really appricate if you up vote)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done pretty easily with `<v-text-field textarea auto-grow>` and some basic flexbox: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jKaVZO

Comment: Hi, thanks for replyng. I am struggling with this solution as I try to limit the input height and it doesn't work well when doing so. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: set `max-height` and `overflow-y: auto` on `.user-input`

Comment: I have done this. However the beahviour is un expected.

Comment: Whenever I write in the text area, there is a problem with the scroll which jumps upwards.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to make a floating button to send messages to a certain number using the whatsapp api. I created a chat box that simulates whatsapp chat.

Basically it was made with vue and the incredible components of vuetify

Add quick whatsapp floating button with message box to connect with your users. If you click on that button, the chat box will open with prefilled message.

[See Codepen](https://codepen.io/carlos-henreis/pen/qvKWVp)

JS

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    fab: false,
    fav: true,
    menu: false,
    message: false,
    hints: true,
    phone: '5521997642382',
    text: "",
    apilink: ""
  }),
  watch: {
        text(val) {
            this.apilink = 'http://';
      this.apilink += this.isMobile() ? 'api' : 'web';
      this.apilink += '.whatsapp.com/send?phone=' + this.phone + '&text=' + encodeURI(this.text);
        }
    },
  created: function () {
    this.apilink = 'http://';
    this.apilink += this.isMobile() ? 'api' : 'web';
    this.apilink += '.whatsapp.com/send?phone=' + this.phone + '&text=' + encodeURI("Hello!");
  },
    methods: {
    isMobile() {
      var check = false;
      (function(a){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4))) check = true;})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
      return check;
    }
  }
})
```

CSS

```
.my-input.v-input .v-input__slot {
  border-radius: 100px;
}
.chat-background {
  background-color: #ECE5DD !important
}
.chat-header {
  background-color: #075E54 !important
}
.chip-chat {
  background-color: #DCF8C6 !important
}
```

html

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <div class="text-xs-center">
      <v-menu
        min-width = 300
        top
        v-model="menu"
        :close-on-click="false"
        :close-on-content-click="false"
        :nudge-top="60"
        offset-x
      >
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
          <v-fab-transition>
            <v-btn
              v-model="fab"
              v-on="on"
              color='green darken-1'
              @click="fab = !fab; menu = false"
              dark
              fixed
              bottom
              right
              fab
            >
              <v-icon>comment</v-icon>
              <v-icon>close</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
          </v-fab-transition>
        </template>
        <v-card>
          <v-list dark class="chat-header">
            <v-list-tile>
              <v-list-tile-content>
                <v-list-tile-title>Contact me</v-list-tile-title>
              </v-list-tile-content>
              <v-list-tile-action>
                <v-btn
                  icon
                  @click="fab = !fab; menu = false"
                >
                  <v-icon>cancel</v-icon>
                </v-btn>
              </v-list-tile-action>
            </v-list-tile>
          </v-list>
          <v-divider></v-divider>
          <v-container class="chat-background">
            <v-layout row wrap >
              <v-flex class="text-xs-right" xs12 mb-4>
                <v-chip class="chip-chat ">
                  Hello, how can we help you? <v-icon right>done_all</v-icon>
                </v-chip>
              </v-flex>
              <v-flex xs10>
                <v-text-field
                  single-line
                  color="teal"
                  class="my-input"
                  v-model="text"
                  outline
                ></v-text-field>
              </v-flex>
              <v-flex xs2>
                <v-btn
                  large
                  class="teal--text"
                  icon
                  @click="fab = !fab; menu = false"
                  :href="apilink"
                  target="_blank"
                >
                  <v-icon large>send</v-icon>
                </v-btn>
               </v-flex>
             </v-layout>  
          </v-container>
        </v-card>  
      </v-menu>   
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Image example

[image: Image example]