# In vue, getting the size of an element is smaller in updated and nextTick than expected?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm trying to get the height of an element. If I try to get it too early, the height is 0px. I tried many different ways to get the height: in mounted(), in created(), on nextTick(), in updated(), and using window.eventListener, but I either get 0px or a size much smaller than I'd expect it to be (~117px). When I run the same command in the console on the page, I get the size I would expect it to be (~278px). If I resize the window, everything works fine. How can I get it to get the right height from the start?

In a vue file, I have:

```
    mounted() {
        this.$nextTick(() => {
            this.vtextHeight = (document.getElementById(this.item.id).offsetHeight - document.getElementsByClassName("v-card__title")[0].offsetHeight) + 'px';
            console.log("next tick", this.vtextHeight);
        });
    },

    updated() {
        this.vtextHeight = (document.getElementById(this.item.id).offsetHeight - document.getElementsByClassName("v-card__title")[0].offsetHeight) + 'px';
        console.log("updated", this.vtextHeight);
    },

    created () {
        var page = this;
        var itemId = this.item.id;

        window.addEventListener('load', () => {
            page.vtextHeight = (document.getElementById(itemId).offsetHeight - document.getElementsByClassName("v-card__title")[0].offsetHeight) + 'px';
            console.log("on load");
        });
        window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
            page.vtextHeight = (document.getElementById(itemId).offsetHeight - document.getElementsByClassName("v-card__title")[0].offsetHeight) + 'px';
            console.log("resize", page.vtextHeight);
        });
    }
```

On the page load:

- "on load" never gets logged
- "next tick 117px" and "updated 117px" gets logged, but that's smaller than I'd expect it to be

On a 1px window resize:

- "resize 278px" and "updated 278px" gets logged, which is the value I'd expect it to be.

Comment: What does your template look like? What sort of element are you trying to query?

Comment: I'm using Vuetify's v-card, v-card-title, and v-card text. The v-card is inside of a div created by a dependency I'm using, but it has a set width and height and has the id stored in this.item.id. I want to make the v-cart-text scrollable, but I seem to only be able to do this by setting the height of the v-card text as the height of the div minus the v-card-title

Answer (score 1):

you can use vue specific `ref` approach to access DOM elements.

For example :

```
 <div class="v-card__title" ref="vCard" :style="{'width': '100px', 'height': '200px'}">
```

Access the element height like this,

```
this.$refs.vCard.offsetHeight + 'px';
```

You can learn ref attribure [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-refs)

View similar stack overflow question [Get element height with Vuejs here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44948714/get-element-height-with-vuejs/44949482).

Comment: It still shows 117px when the page is first rendered. I have no idea where it's getting that size from.

Comment: I was actually looking at the wrong console log, but I'm having issues with using $refs. I logged:

`var cardRef = 'card-' + itemId;
console.log("getting card height of: " + cardRef);
console.log("refs again", this.$refs);
console.log("ref card: ", this.$refs[cardRef]);`

Printed, I get:
`getting card height of: card-XEQxYe7e
refs again 
{}
card-XEQxYe7e: [VueComponent]
card-0MG4FiRWN: [VueComponent]
card-42r-tHs6L: [VueComponent]
card-e5_Ip9gj: [VueComponent]
__proto__: Object
ref card:  undefined`

When I hover over the name, it shows ""card-XEQxYe7e"". Why 4 quotes?

Comment: Also, my code in the v-card is: `:ref="'card-' + item.id"`

Comment: Following what was done here: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/solved-this-refs-key-returns-undefined-when-it-really-is/1226/2 I found that refs isn't populated yet, but I'm calling the code in mounted() so I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: So removing the '-' seemed to work, and now I can get the ref properly, but `this.$refs[cardRef][0].clientHeight` is undefined

Comment: Solved! Instead of using clientHeight, I dug deep into the ref and found a hidden variable that had the height in it, which I then used. Thanks!