# How to wrap table headers consistently?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table where headers are dates formatted as `moment().format('dd D MMM')`. Sometimes they can be wrapped and it's fine, but if any header was automatically wrapped I want to force other headers to be wrapped consistently.

The problem with [inconsistent wrapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYApr.png)

```
|          | Mo 5 |          | We 7 |          |          | Sa 10 |
| Su 4 Oct | Oct  | Tu 6 Oct | Oct  | Th 8 Oct | Fr 9 Oct | Oct   |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I want it to be [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48koz.png)

```
| Su 4 | Mo 5 | Tu 6 | We 7 | Th 8 | Fr 9 | Sa 10 |
| Oct  | Oct  | Oct  | Oct  | Oct  | Oct  | Oct   |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

It becomes even worse with different scales when [three lines in one cell appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZgKF.png). I'm wondering if there is a way to always have the same number of lines (equal to maximum) in all header cells

The table is a regular bootstrap table with no custom classes (I'm using bootstrap-vue)

`<b-table striped borderless show-empty id="timeInputs" :items="items" :fields="fields" :sort-compare="tableSort"></b-table>`

This is the code of the rendered table:

```html
<table id="timeInputs" role="table" aria-busy="false" aria-colcount="9" class="table b-table table-striped table-borderless" aria-rowcount="13">
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <thead role="rowgroup" class="">
    <!---->
    <tr role="row" class="">
      <th role="columnheader" scope="col" tabindex="0" aria-colindex="1" aria-sort="none" class="">
        <div>Name</div>
        <span class="sr-only"> (Click to sort Ascending)</span>
      </th>
      <th role="columnheader" scope="col" tabindex="0" aria-colindex="2" aria-label="Expand" class="">
        <div></div>
      </th>
      <th role="columnheader" scope="col" tabindex="0" aria-colindex="3" class="">
        <div id="sun-header">Su 25 Oct</div>
      </th>
      <th role="columnheader" scope="col" tabindex="0" aria-colindex="4" class="">
        <div>Mo 26 Oct</div>
      </th>
      <th role="columnheader" scope="col" tabindex="0" aria-colindex="5" class="">
        <div>Tu 27 Oct</div>
      </th>
      <th role="columnheader" scope="col" tabindex="0" aria-colindex="6" class="">
        <div>We 28 Oct</div>
      </th>
      <th role="columnheader" scope="col" tabindex="0" aria-colindex="7" class="">
        <div>Th 29 Oct</div>
      </th>
      <th role="columnheader" scope="col" tabindex="0" aria-colindex="8" class="">
        <div>Fr 30 Oct</div>
      </th>
      <th role="columnheader" scope="col" tabindex="0" aria-colindex="9" class="">
        <div>Sa 31 Oct</div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  ...
</table>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Do you have the option to use to Javascript? You could use JS to find the cell with the biggest height and then set the other cells to the same height and width.

Comment: Please also add more of your table code, at least the table, thead and the tr in question

Comment: I can use JS, but I was thinking if there is a simple way to do it with css. It seemed to me too overpowered to do such a simple task using js.

Comment: CSS is implemented when the page loads, so you could use CSS to set a fixed height and width for all cells, but you couldn't dynamically determine which cell is the biggest and then make the others match. If you don't care about having the cells be as small as possible while still being consistent, this is a fine solution.

Comment: I just added full table code. It's only uses default bootstrap-vue b-table properties to put data inside it

Comment: Can you include what the rendered table looks like? With the `thead`, `tr`, etc?

Comment: @Chiperific got it, thank you!

Comment: @Chiperific just added the rendered table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it's not possible to do it just with css

So, I had to use JS to [calculate the height](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-count-text-lines-inside-of-dom-element/) of the tallest header and then [manually update other headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44948714/get-element-height-with-vuejs) to match the tallest one.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#timeinputs th {
  // set a fixed width and height that works for your biggest possible value
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
}
```

Else, as mentioned in the comments, you can use some Javascript to find the "largest" cell and set the other cells to match.