# Get element's height value with composition api

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

A question like this:
What exists today is the easiest way to get a reactive value of the height of an element, provided that specific parameters for this height are not specified.
I am primarily interested in the implementation in conjunction with the `Vue3 Composition Api`

Tried options like the following:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

But they all didn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get element height with Vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44948714/get-element-height-with-vuejs)

Comment: Is it in the 3rd version nothing better appeared?

Comment: http://joxi.ru/EA4dWyzHXVw7lA
http://joxi.ru/n2YLbPaHkEoN8m
Besides, that is not work at all in 3-rd version

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this

template:

```
<ul ref="infoBox"></ul>
```

script:

```
const infoBox = ref(0)

const height = infoBox.value.clientHeight
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<template>
    <div ref="refDiv"></div>  
<\template>
<script setup>
import {ref, onMounted} from 'vue';
const refDiv = ref(null);
onMounted(()=>{
console.log(refDiv.value.clientWidth,refDiv.value.clientHeigth)
})
```