# Get the height of an element in Vue 3 functional component

Tags: vuejs3

I've seen this:
[Get element height with Vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44948714/get-element-height-with-vuejs)
But from my understanding, functional component doesnt have this keyword.
How can I get the height of a HTML element in vue.
I'm from a React background and would just use refs there but refs in vue dont seem to be the same. Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple example using composition API:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Cool Title</h1>
        <BaseTestData ref="test"></BaseTestData>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const test = ref(null)

onMounted(() => {
    console.log(test.value.$el.clientHeight)
})
</script>
```

Comment: What is the proper way to go about typescript in this example? 

When I try:
const calendarHeader = ref<HTMLElement | undefined>()

and then access in onMounted like:
calendarHeader.value!.$el.clientHeight

I get: 'property $el does not exist on HTMLElement'

Comment: `calendarHeader.value!.clientHeight` should do the trick for you. You don't need the `$el`.