# object.style.maxHeight doesnt work if maxHeight is define at css

Tags: javascript, css, html

I just want to get the  maxHeight of an element previously define at css but doesnt work.
It only works if I modify it explicitly with javascript first

[Code](http://jsbin.com/nozupak/edit?html,css,js,output)

```js
let something=document.querySelector(".something");
let before=document.querySelector(".before");
let after=document.querySelector(".after");
before.textContent=something.style.maxHeight
something.style.maxHeight="20px";
after.textContent=something.style.maxHeight;
```

```css
.before::before{
  content:'Before:'
}
.after::before{
  content:'After: '
}
.something{max-height:30px}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="something">
       Something very cool  
  </div>
  <div class="before">
   Before:
  </div>
  <div class="after">
   After:
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Any recomendation about how can I do it without to define max-height with javascript in all my elements? .Ignore the fact that I write "before;" and "after:" inside divs(I can´t edit). Thank you

Comment: I don't have time to find a dupe, but like most css property, you can access the computed value through [`window.getComputedStyle(element)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I thought it was gonna be computable expensive but I was wrong, it takes almost the same time to compute if something.style.maxHeight would work  [link](http://jsbin.com/muwuva/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: Your tests doesn't prove anything. If getComputedStyle is expensive it is because the browser has to perform a reflow of the page, but once it's been done, it won't redo it, except if you changed the styles in-between calls of course. So if you are doing a lot of DOM manip and call it at every changes, it will have a bad impact on performances. You should use it with care, just like anything else btw.

Comment: I said it wasnt computable expensive, but anyway thaks for aclaration

Comment: And I said it might be, if not used properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I did a little digging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) and found an answer for you, just replace your line with this:

```
before.textContent=window.getComputedStyle(something).maxHeight
```

[Code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

```js
let something=document.querySelector(".something");
let before=document.querySelector(".before");
let after=document.querySelector(".after");
before.textContent=window.getComputedStyle(something).maxHeight; // the fix!!!
something.style.maxHeight="20px";
after.textContent=something.style.maxHeight;
```

```css
.before::before{
  content:'Before:'
}
.after::before{
  content:'After: '
}
.something{max-height:30px}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="something">
       Something very cool  
  </div>
  <div class="before">
   Before:
  </div>
  <div class="after">
   After:
  </div>
</body>
```

---

alternatively: you can get the element current rendered height by doing so:
[How do you get the rendered height of an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526347/how-do-you-get-the-rendered-height-of-an-element)

Comment: .something{max-height:30px}  <- that is the max-height declared at css

Comment: You're right, I did a little digging and found a solution - window.getComputedStyle. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I thought it was gonna be computable expensive but I was wrong, it takes almost the same time to compute if something.style.maxHeight would work [link here](http://jsbin.com/muwuva/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: Yeah you might have dug [really far](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48979306/#comment-84964308)...

Comment: @Kaiido I must have passed over your answer, sorry. It is valid as well.