# Working with CSS Grid and layout alignment

Tags: html, css, nav, css-grid

I am trying to put a background behind the whole css grid I have you can see the tomato color in the body, but I want that background color to be fully around the main tag. I tried a bunch different ways to wrap it, but something I have is conflicting.

One other thing is I can't get the gird to also start under the nav bar and I want the nav bar to stretch across the top and not overlapping when the page first loads. I am not sure if the correct way would be to just put a margin. I want to think there is some type of other way to do this.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/raregamer/6jea2wdw/2/)

```
body {
background: tomato;

/* font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
line-height: 1.5; */
font: normal 1em/1.5 Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
margin: 0px auto;
padding: 0px;
width:80%
}

html{
    background: linear-gradient(to right, palegreen,paleturquoise, plum);

}

/* main */
main{
    width: 85%;
    height: 80px;
    margin:.5em  auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
    grid-gap: 1em;
}

main > div:nth-child(odd){
    background: peachpuff;

}

main > div {
    background: palegreen;
    padding: 1em;
    border-radius: 20px;

}
```

to show what is happening so if anyone know hows to fix it please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the `height` in main would fix the background color issue.

```
main{
    width: 85%;
    margin:.5em  auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
    grid-gap: 1em;
}
```

Add `left:0` to top nav bar.

```
nav{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.507);
    display:grid; 
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    height: 50px;;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left: 0px; /*add this to stretch */
}
```

Giving `margin-top` to main is not a bad idea. It is the normal way of doing it.

Comment: Thank You!, I knew I kept over looking something.

Answer (score 0):

Your `main` element had a fixed height of 80px which I removed.

In order to start the content after the navbar, I added a `margin-top` of the `height` of the `navbar`.
You could also do it via Javascript if your navbar might have a dynamic height, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526347/how-do-you-get-the-rendered-height-of-an-element) to get the height and [on how to apply css via js](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp).

```css
body {
    background:tomato;

    /* font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.5; */
    font: normal 1em/1.5 Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    width:80%;
    }

    html{
        background: linear-gradient(to right, palegreen,paleturquoise, plum);

    }


    

    /* nav top bar  */
nav{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.507);
    display:grid; 
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;

    

}

/* logo adjustments */

#logo{
    text-align: center; 

}

 #logo > img{
    
    border-radius: 20%;
    height: 35px;
    margin: .5em;
 }

/* main */
main{
    
    width: 85%;
    margin:.5em  auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
    grid-gap: 1em;
    
}

main > div:nth-child(odd){
    background: peachpuff;

}

main > div {
    background: palegreen;
    padding: 1em;
    border-radius: 20px;

}


/* Side navigation menu */

.sidenav {
    height: 100%; /* 100% Full-height */
    width: 0; /* 0 width - change this with JavaScript */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Stay on top */
    top: 0;  /* Stay on top */
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111; /*black*/
    padding-top: 60px; /* Place content 60px from the top */
    transition: 0.5s; /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in the sidenav */
    overflow-x: hidden;

}

/* The navigation menu links */
.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

/* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */
.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Position and style the close button (top right corner) */
.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/backgroundgrid.css">
    <script src="js/javascript.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script" type='text/css'>


</head>

<body>

    <header>

        <nav>
            <div id="sideNavBar" class="sidenav">

                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
                <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                <a href="resume.html">Resume</a>
                <a href="#">Page 2</a>
                <a href="#">Page 3</a>

            </div>

            <!-- Use any element to open the sidenav -->
            <span style="font-size:35px;cursor:pointer;margin-left:.5em;" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; </span>

            <span id="logo">
                <img src="images/logosamuelsmall.png">
            </span>


        </nav>


    </header>

    <main>
        <div>gfdgdf</div>

        <div>
            <div class="card-container">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="side">
                        <h3 class="heading-banner head-text">Background</h3>
                    </div>

                    <div class="side back">

                        <ul>
                            <li>I'm an aspiring software engineer who loves creating new software that is playful, interactive
                                and has heart. I've lived in lots of different places and have worked in lots of different
                                jobs. I’m excited to work on teams that support, learn, and build the amazing. </li>
                            <li>I've been working with technology, customer support and sales for 10+ years. </li>
                            <li>I love music, cooking and learning</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>gfdgdf</div>

        <div>
            <div class="card-container">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="side">
                        <h3 class="heading-banner head-text">Background</h3>
                    </div>

                    <div class="side back">

                        <ul>
                            <li>I'm an aspiring software engineer who loves creating new software that is playful, interactive
                                and has heart. I've lived in lots of different places and have worked in lots of different
                                jobs. I’m excited to work on teams that support, learn, and build the amazing. </li>
                            <li>I've been working with technology, customer support and sales for 10+ years. </li>
                            <li>I love music, cooking and learning</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div>gfdgdf</div>

        <div>
            <div class="card-container">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="side">
                        <h3 class="heading-banner head-text">Background</h3>
                    </div>

                    <div class="side back">

                        <ul>
                            <li>I'm an aspiring software engineer who loves creating new software that is playful, interactive
                                and has heart. I've lived in lots of different places and have worked in lots of different
                                jobs. I’m excited to work on teams that support, learn, and build the amazing. </li>
                            <li>I've been working with technology, customer support and sales for 10+ years. </li>
                            <li>I love music, cooking and learning</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </main>

</body>


</html>
```