# How to position a DIV beneath a fixed DIV with dynamic size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got something like a `navigation bar` which is fixed on the top of the side. Now I want to have a `content-DIV` which is beneath it. The problem is, that the navigation bar has no fixed height.

How can I achieve this?

HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
this is my navigation bar
</div>
<div id="content">
HERE <br>
IS <br>
MUCH <br>
CONTENT
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#nav {
  position: fixed;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

JSFIDDLE: [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/zw453sfn/)

Comment: put both of them in a wrapper and add position fixed to that wrapper

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa How can I get it scrolling when doing this? http://jsfiddle.net/zw453sfn/9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Pure Javascript solution

With javascript, you can get the height and the position of your `<div id="nav">` and use them to compute the position of your `<div id="content">`:

```
var navDivElement = document.getElementById("nav");
var contentDivElement = document.getElementById("content");

contentDivElement.style.top = navDivElement.clientHeight + navDivElement.getBoundingClientRect().top + 'px';
```

### Presision

#### How to get the position of an element:

```
var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
console.log(rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom, rect.left);
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11396681/4032282

#### How to get the dimensions of an element:

```
var e = document.getElementById('id')
console.log(e.clientHeight, e.offsetHeight, e.scrollHeight);
```

- `clientHeight` includes the height and vertical padding.
- `offsetHeight` includes the height, vertical padding, and vertical borders.
- `scrollHeight` includes the height of the contained document (would be greater than just height in case of scrolling), vertical padding, and vertical borders.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/526352/4032282

## CSS Sticky solution

Change the `position: fixed;` of the nav by `position: sticky;` and add a `top: 0;`.

That way the `<div id="content">` will be placed under the nav, but the nav will stay on the top of his container.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    #nav {
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
    }

    /* Allow you to play with the browser height to make the vertical scroll appears and use it to see that the nav will stay on top */
    #content {
      height: 500px;
      background-color: #ff0000;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="nav">NAV</div>
    <div id="content">CONTENT</div>
  </body>
</html>
```