# Height of an element that is not rendert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526347/how-do-you-get-the-rendered-height-of-an-element) to get the height of an element that has not height Attribute. But is it possible to get or calculate the height before it is rendert?

for example I have this Code:

```
var element = createElement("div");
element.style.width = "20px";
element.innerHTML = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
```

If I know the fontsize and other stuff like padding etc. , is it possible to get the height it would have if it gets rendert?

I need this because I need to know how heigh the element is before it gets rendert to change things that happens after that.

Comment: Short answer, no. You cannot get the height of an element that isn't part of the DOM. A quick fix is to append it to the DOM in an absolute position that's well off the screen, eg `left: -9999px` and then get its size. Be aware that this element won't inherit any styling from its parents though, if that's relevant to your situation

Comment: But it would be possible to calculate how many rows it would have if I dont need the exact height, right?

Comment: What do you mean by 'rows'? You're appending a div, not a table. Did you mean lines of text? If so, yes. That would be `height / line height`

Comment: Yes I mean lines of text. But how can I do `height / line height` if I dont have the height of the div?

Comment: You can get the height of the div through the method I described in my first comment...?

Comment: Yeah but I mean without your workaround to Display it somewhere. My current solution is now just counting the chars.