# Change element dimensions with the ratio another element changed with

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, math

In this example:
[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/nh38zxe0/2/)

I have a [Picture](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs/master/docs/images/picture.jpg) with dimensions `835x470`, That image is added to 2 elements, A hidden `<img>` and as a background to a `<div>` width class `wrapper`, I set the `<div>` dimensions to smaller dimensions `519x220` on my screen.

There is a centered circular element on the `<div>` with the dimensions `100x100`, I want to set these dimensions with the same ratio the image changed from `835x470` to `519x220`.

So for example if the circle on the original image `835x470` was `200x200`, When the `<div>` dimensions are set/changed to `519x220`, The circle would take the same space it took on the original image, Which were `200x200`.

So if the `200x200` represented `15%` for example from the `835x470`, Then the circle would take the same `15%` from the new dimensions `519x220`

What I tried to do is that I get the natural dimensions of the image `835x470` and get the new dimension of the image `519x220` and divide each dimension to get a ratio, Then check to get the smallest ratio (Not to make the circle be out of the image), Then multiply this ratio by `200` and set it as `width` and `height` of the image.

Here is the code:

```js
//Get natural dimensions from the hidden image.
var imgNaturalHeight = document.getElementById('img').naturalHeight,
    imgNaturalWidth = document.getElementById('img').naturalWidth,
    
    //Get new dimensions from the wrapper that has the image as a background.
    imgNewHeight = document.querySelector('.wrapper').height,
    imgNewWidth = document.querySelector('.wrapper').width,

    //Get height and width ratios.
    widthRatio = imgNewWidth / imgNaturalWidth,
    heightRatio = imgNewHeight / imgNaturalHeight,
    
    //Define ratio variable.
    ratio;

//Set ratio to the smallest ratio.
if ( widthRatio < heightRatio ) {
  ratio = widthRatio;
}else{
  ratio = heightRatio;
}

//The new value for width and height
var fixed = ratio * 200;

//Set the new width and height of the circle.
document.querySelector('.overlay').style.width = fixed;
document.querySelector('.overlay').style.height = fixed;
```

```css
.wrapper{
  position: relative; 
  background: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs/master/docs/images/picture.jpg');
  height:220px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}

.overlay{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.image{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>

<img id="img" class="image" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs/master/docs/images/picture.jpg" >
```

I hope I made it clear.

Comment: And what's wrong with your approach?

Comment: @MBo, The circle dimensions is not changed to the new dimensions and I'm not sure if these calculations would achieve what I want

Comment: Calculations look fine. But I see that circle size depends on values in CSS, but couldn't be changed from code (try `..width = 500;`). So problem is not in math, but in JS execution/interaction

Comment: @MBo, if the circle when it was `200x200` represented `15%` for example from the original image dimensions  `835x470`, Then the new dimensions should take `15%` from the new dimensions `519x220`

Comment: Yes, it is calculated. But is not applied (I don't know why - not JS guy)

Answer (score 0):

> So that it takes the same space it took on the original image, Which were 200x200.

Try to follow this steps:

- calculate ratio of **new to old** image with and height
- multiply **original circle dimensions** by its ratio

This should do the trick.

There is some example (maybe not exactly your case but I hope you can adapt it easily).

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/nh38zxe0/16/)

Note: Im not so sure what you try to achieve in pure JS so I used `clientHeight` property, you can read about other possibilities here [Height and width in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526347/how-do-you-get-the-rendered-height-of-an-element)

Comment: I forgot to add `px` at the end, Thanks for that, But on my example after I added the `px` it still not working

Comment: `clientHeight` and `clientWidtht` did the effect

Comment: its baecuse of this line `imgNewHeight = document.querySelector('.wrapper').height`
try to add `alert(imgNewHeight);` somewhere in your code for simple debugging, you will get "undefined", read about getting objects dimensions in JavaScript to know how to get them porperly

Answer (score 0):

```
//Get natural dimensions from the hidden image.
var imgNaturalHeight = document.getElementById('img').naturalHeight,
    imgNaturalWidth = document.getElementById('img').naturalWidth,

    //Get new dimensions from the wrapper that has the image as a background.
    imgNewHeight = document.querySelector('.wrapper').clientHeight,
    imgNewWidth = document.querySelector('.wrapper').clientWidth,

    //Get height and width ratios.
    widthRatio = imgNewWidth / imgNaturalWidth,
    heightRatio = imgNewHeight / imgNaturalHeight,

    //Define ratio variable.
    ratio;

//Set ratio to the smallest ratio.
if ( widthRatio < heightRatio ) {
  ratio = widthRatio;
}else{
  ratio = heightRatio;
}

//The new value for width and height
var fixed = ratio * 200;

//Set the new width and height of the circle.
document.querySelector('.overlay').style.width = fixed + "px";
document.querySelector('.overlay').style.height = fixed + "px"
```