# Looping through each element and logging the height

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to log the height of each of the `.slide-text-overlay` elements, but no value seems to be showing. The simple for of loop should loop through each class and just log the html of that class and then the height - but the height isn't logging; instead, just an empty line in the console.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks for any help

```js
var overlays = document.querySelectorAll('.overlay');
for (let overlay of overlays) {
  console.log(overlay);
  console.log(overlay.style.height);
}
```

```css
.overlay:first-of-type {
color: red;
width: 100px;
height: 50px;
background: orange;
}
.overlay:nth-of-type(2) {
color: blue;
width: 100px;
height: 75px;
background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class='overlay'>
overlay 1
</div>
<div class='overlay'>
overlay 2
</div>
```

Comment: Your markup doesn't have `slide-text-overlay` class.

Comment: oops yes I meant '.overlay', but still the problem is exactly the same (I've updated the demo btw) - it just logs as ''" - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/arNJJw?editors=1111

Comment: Try `overlay.getBoundingClientRect().height` instead of `overlay.style.height`

Comment: `overlay.clientHeight` [How do you get the rendered height of an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28155507/3082296)

Comment: thanks both - both worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the offset Height in JS

```js
var overlays = document.querySelectorAll('.overlay');
for (var i=0; i < overlays.length; i++) {
  console.log(overlays[i].offsetHeight)
}
```

```css
.overlay:first-of-type {
  color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: orange;
}
.overlay:nth-of-type(2) {
  color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='overlay'>
  overlay 1
</div>
<div class='overlay'>
  overlay 2
</div>
```

> Documentation:
>   https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_offsetheight.asp

Answer (score 1):

The class in the querySelector should be overlay

```js
var overlays = document.querySelectorAll('.overlay');
for (let overlay of overlays) {
  console.log(overlay);
  console.log(overlay.style.height);
}
```

```css
.overlay:first-of-type {
color: red;
width: 100px;
height: 50px;
background: orange;
}
.overlay:nth-of-type(2) {
color: blue;
width: 100px;
height: 75px;
background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class='overlay'>
overlay 1
</div>
<div class='overlay'>
overlay 2
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var overlays = document.getElementsByClass('.overlay');
for (let overlay of overlays) {
  console.log(overlay);
  console.log(overlay.style.height);
}
```