# How to get the specified height of a div in javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am drawing a chart

```
<canvas id="mychart" width="421" height="280" class="chartjs-render-monitor" style="display: block; width: 421px; height: 280px;"></canvas>
```

How do I get the height in javascript

Ihave tried this

```
var ctx = document.getElementById(params.placeHolder);
console.log(ctx.height)
```

It's returning 150 instead of 280

Comment: What is `params.placeHolder`?

Comment: Note that 300x150 are the default measurements of a canvas, so my first guess is you're logging some other canvas's height maybe. If I set `params.placeHolder` to `mychart`, your code works as expected. Still, getting the height like that is potentially unsafe; what is your goal here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the offsetHeight.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("mychart");
console.log(ctx.offsetHeight)
```

```html
<canvas id="mychart" width="421" height="280" class="chartjs-render-monitor" style="display: block; width: 421px; height: 280px;"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery, try with:

```
$('#mychart').height();
```

With pure JS, try some of these:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById(params.placeHolder).clientHeight;
var ctx = document.getElementById(params.placeHolder).offsetHeight;
var ctx = document.getElementById(params.placeHolder).scrollHeight;
```

.scrollHeight

**clientHeight** includes the height and vertical padding.

**offsetHeight** includes the height, vertical padding, and vertical borders.

**scrollHeight** includes the height of the contained document (would be greater than just height in case of scrolling), vertical padding, and vertical borders.

Got this last response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526347/how-do-you-get-the-rendered-height-of-an-element)